# jQuery: each radio button each addClass to a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a group of nine Radio buttons and when I click each radio button I want add a different class (avatar1, avatar2, avatar3, ...) to a div with id="avatar".

```
<div class="ediar_avatar">
    <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" class="av1">
    <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" class="av2">
    <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" class="av3">
    <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" class="av4">
    <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" class="av5">
    <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" class="av6">
    <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" class="av7">
    <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" class="av8">
    <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" class="av9">
  </div>
```

I tried this jquery:

```
jQuery('.av1').click(function(){
            if (this.checked) {
                $("#avatar").attr('class', '');
                $('#avatar').addClass('avatar1')
            }
```

but I have to do the same for each radio buton and it is a long code. There are any way to make it shorter, for example with a cycle?

Comment: Since you are using same name `RadioGroup1` for radio, so at a time only one radio is gona be selected.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `index`:

```
jQuery('[class^=av').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#avatar").removeAttr('class').addClass('avatar' + ($(this).index() + 1));
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3cx3m2fo/

Answer (score 0):

With your current markup you can get the classname from the clicked radios classname like

```
jQuery('.ediar_avatar input:radio').click(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $("#avatar").attr('class', 'avatar1' + this.className.match(/\d+$/)[0]);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
jQuery('.av1').click(function(){
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $("#avatar").attr('class', '');
                $('#avatar').addClass('avatar1')
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `input[name="RadioGroup1"]` in selector and use `.index() + 1`  to get the index of input

```
jQuery('input[name="RadioGroup1"]').click(function(){
            if (this.checked) {
                $("#avatar").attr('class', ''); 
                $('#avatar').addClass('avatar'+ (($(this).index()) + 1));
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works perfectly. The line you say it is not necessary,it is to clean the class attr, because without it, put all classes one after another to #avatar and eventually fails to recognize which should prevail. Thank you very much: D

Answer (score 0):

make your HTML like this

```
<div class="ediar_avatar">
    <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1[]" class="av1">
    <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1[]" class="av2">
    <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1[]" class="av3">
    <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1[]" class="av4">
    <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1[]" class="av5">
    <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1[]" class="av6">
    <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1[]" class="av7">
    <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1[]" class="av8">
    <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1[]" class="av9">
  </div>
```

I changed the `name` of each of your `radio button`

Your jQuery like this

```
jQuery('.ediar_avatar input:radio').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#avatar").addClass('avatar' + $(this).index() + 1);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can simply remove and add class after selection is made using Jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("input").on("change", function() {

    $("div").removeClass();
    $("div").addClass($(this).attr("class"));
    alert("div class now is:"+$("div").attr("class"));

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ediar_avatar">
  <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" class="av1">
  <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" class="av2">
  <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" class="av3">
  <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" class="av4">
  <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" class="av5">
  <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" class="av6">
  <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" class="av7">
  <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" class="av8">
  <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" class="av9">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following jQuery code:-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
         if (this.checked) {
            currIndex = $(this).index();    
            currIndex = currIndex+1;    
            $(this).attr('class', '');
            $(this).addClass('avatar'+currIndex)
        }
        });
  });
```